# How to edit latex-generated text in Captions?

Tags: listings

I want to take the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742069/979621) to the question [LaTeX source code listing like in professional books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books) one step further, and change the (latex-generated) text in the caption from `Listing n` to something more personalized, like `Code Snippet n`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Okay. How can I migrate this question? Or should I repost?

Comment: You can flag it for attention by a moderator, and ask them to migrate it.

Comment: Makoto is right, it is described in [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/176951)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\renewcommand*` to change the value from `Listing` to whatever you wish.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
Some dummy text.

\renewcommand*\lstlistingname{Example}
% Some helpers that made C code look passable in a report
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={C code},label=C, language=C, basicstyle=\ttfamily, keywordstyle=\normalsize, identifierstyle=\normalsize, stringstyle=\normalsize, showstringspaces=false]

for (j = 0; j < 20; ++j) {  
        while ((c = getchar()) != '-') {
            printf("j=%d\n", j);
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n')
                ++j;
            else
                length[j]++;
        }
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How does \renewcommand* differ from \renewcommand?

Comment: @SNag:  I don't think there is any (tested it out when you asked the question).  It's the command that appeared in some of my old printoffs about TeX, and that's the one manual I had to grab when I answered this.